# Test score bigger than Train score in Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, train

I'm new to ML and I'm trying to create a linear regression model. My data consist of 100 samples with 4 features each. This is my humble code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=80)


reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
score_test = reg.score(X_test, y_test)
score_train = reg.score(X_train, y_train)
print("Train Score is :", score_train)
print("Test Score is :", score_test)
```

The problem is that the score in Test set (0.97) is way bigger than the score in Train set (0.71). How we can explain this?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you perhaps misinterpreted what "score" is meant to be doing? From the sci kit learn website:

> .score( ) Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction

It is not looking at the accuracy measure of your regression, but the R^2 value of your regression fit of your linear regression on your training data set. It doesn't make sense to use it again on the testing data (that's not how R^2 is supposed to work).

Comment: But shouldn't the R^2 score in the train set be bigger than R^2 score in the test set??

Comment: Please refer to this anawer. I think it may help in your understanding https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320519/117574

Comment: Also imagine if your test set were two data points, and these two points completely lie on your model regression line by chance. It would have an R^2 value of 1.

Comment: Also if you are happy with my answer please dont forget to mark it as accepted by using the tick :)